# Using shared_from_this() without managed shared pointer in C++11

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, std, shared-ptr

Let's say I have a class which is a child class of enable_shared_from_this. The documentation of this base class says there should be a shared pointer which owns this class before calling shared_from_this. Is it safe to allocate the class with new and call shared_from_this to manage the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not safe. You should only call `shared_from_this` if the object is managed by a `shared_ptr`, not allocated via `new` (without an associated `shared_ptr`). For example this code

```
struct Test: std::enable_shared_from_this<Test> {
  std::shared_ptr<Test> getptr() {
    return shared_from_this();
  }
};

Test *test = new Test;
std::shared_ptr<Test> test2 = test->getptr();
```

will throw `std::bad_weak_ptr` (at least when using `libstdc++`). But this is OK:

```
std::shared_ptr<Test> test(new Test);
std::shared_ptr<Test> test2 = test->getptr();
```

Comment: What happens with test2 when I start managing a new pointer with test after the call to test->getptr(). Is this a safe use case? I'm asking this because boost::asio uses a lot of these constructs when starting async receive or write operations.

Comment: @Gustavo You can't start managing the pointer after a call to `getptr` because the latter will throw unless it is already managed (by a shared_ptr).

Comment: I mean the following case:
std::shared_ptr<Test> test(new Test);
std::shared_ptr<Test> test2 = test->getptr();
test.reset(new AnotherTest);
/* Do something with test2 */

Is this a valid use case?

Comment: Looks fine to me. reset simply replaces the managed object and it doesn't matter if it (or other instance) was obtained by shared_from_this or not.

Answer (score 6):

As already mentioned by other users, calls to `shared_from_this` on instances that are not owned by `shared_ptr`s will result in an undefined behavior (usually an exception, but there are no guarantees).

So, why one more answer?

Because I did myself the same question once and got almost the same answer, then I started struggling with another question that immediately arose after that - *how can I guarantee thus that all the instances are managed by a `shared_ptr`*?

For the sake of completeness, I add another answer with a few details about this aspect.
Here a simple solution that had not been mentioned before.

So simple a solution, indeed: *private constructors*, *factory method* and *variadic template*s.
It follows a snippet that mixes all of them together in a minimal example:

```
#include<memory>
#include<utility>

class C: public std::enable_shared_from_this<C> {
    C() = default;
    C(const C &) = default;
    C(C &&) = default;
    C& operator=(const C &) = default;
    C& operator=(C &&c) = default;

public:
    template<typename... Args>
    static std::shared_ptr<C> create(Args&&... args) noexcept {
        return std::shared_ptr<C>{new C{std::forward<Args>(args)...}};
    }

    std::shared_ptr<C> ptr() noexcept {
        return shared_from_this();
    }
};

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<C> c1 = C::create();
    std::shared_ptr<C> c2 = C::create(*c1);
    std::shared_ptr<C> c3 = c2->ptr();
    // these won't work anymore...
    // C c4{};
    // std::shared_ptr<C> c5 = std::make_shared<C>();
    // std::shared_ptr<C> c6{new C{}};
    // C c7{*c1};
    // ... and so on ...
}
```

The basic (trivial?) idea is to forbid the explicit construction of new instances, but by using the factory method here called `create`.
Variadic templates are used to avoid writing several factory methods, nothing more. Perfect forwarding helps us to do that the right way.

Pretty simple, isn't it?
Anyway it took me a while to figure out that, so I hope this will help future readers once across the same doubt.

Comment: I think something like this should be a cpp core guideline.

Answer (score 3):

From the standard:

> § 20.8.2.4
>
> shared_ptr shared_from_this();
>
> shared_ptr shared_from_this() const;
>
> 7 *Requires: enable_shared_from_this shall be an accessible base class of T. **this shall be a
>   subobject of an object t of type T. There shall be at least one shared_ptr instance p that owns &t.**
>
> 8 Returns: A shared_ptr object r that shares ownership with p.
>
> 9 Postconditions: r.get() == this

If you call `shared_from_this()` within a class that is not managed by a `shared_ptr` the result will be **undefined behaviour** because you have not fulfilled one of the documented preconditions of the method.

I know from experience that in [the current version of] libc++ the result is an exception being thrown. However, like all *undefined behavior* this must not be relied upon.

Answer (score 2):

> The documentation of this base class says there should be a shared pointer which owns this [object] before calling shared_from_this.

Okay, cool.

> Is it safe to allocate the [object] with new and call shared_from_this to manage the object?

No. There should be a shared pointer which owns this [object] before calling shared_from_this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not safe at all.
Calling shared_from_this() from a non-shared_ptr invokes a bad_weak_ptr exception.

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct A : std::enable_shared_from_this<A>
{
    A(A *parent, int x): parent(parent), x(x) {
        std::cout << "create A with " << x << std::endl;
    }

    void print(){
        std::cout << "print A : " << x << std::endl;
    }
    ~A(){
        std::cout << "delete A" << std::endl;
    }
    A *parent;
    int x;
};

void useA(const std::shared_ptr<A> &a) {
    a->print();
    a->parent->print();
    for(auto parent = a->parent; parent; parent = parent->parent){
        auto aptr = parent->shared_from_this();
        aptr->print();
    }
    
}

int main() {
    auto a1 = new A(NULL, 0);
    auto p1 = std::make_shared<A>(a1, 1);
    
    std::cout << "main" << std::endl;
    useA(p1);

}
```

In this example, std::bad_weak_ptr is thrown at

> auto aptr = parent->shared_from_this();