# Passing `this` to a function as a shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11

I am writing some example code that hopefully captures my current struggle.
Let's assume I have a class for some general shapes `Shape`
and a nice Function that doubles the perimeter of any shape

```
float DoublePerimeter (shared_ptr<Shape> shape)
  return 2*shape->GetPerimeter();
};
```

Is it possible to use such a function in a class itself?

```
class Square : Shape {
  float side = 1;
  public:
  void Square(float aside) : side(aside) {;}
  float GetPerimeter(){return 4*side;}
  void Computation() { DoublePerimeter (??????);}
};
```

What can I pass in the `??????` to make this work? I tried using something like

```
shared_ptr<Shape> share_this(this);
```

and also tried `enable_shared_from_this<>` for my class, however the pointer that I pass to the function always returns null on lock. Is this even possible, or is this bad design? Am I forced to make this function a member function?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any reason why the function should accept a `shared_ptr` instead of a regular (non-owning) pointer. Why did you define the function that way?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. I am writing my code to be exported to python using pybind11, where I require the pointer to be a `shared_ptr`. I agree, that a non-owning pointer would make life much easier here.

Comment: In that case you cannot really use `this` as a parameter, since it would only work if it refers to an object managed by a `std::shared_ptr` somewhere (as you have found out with your `std::enable_shared_from_this` experiments) - so yes, you have a bit of a design issue here

Comment: `shared_from_this` is only for objects that are already shared and for types inheriting from `enable_shared_from_this`. I guess it has uses, but I dont understand them ;), in any case its a great way to shoot yourself in the foot. Who creates the object and who calls the function?

Comment: you can use a `shared_ptr` with custom deleter that does nothing, but thats also just a workaround, a hack, that avoids to solve the actual problem of design

Comment: `enable_shared_from_this` is the answer I think. Could you show that code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34213087/using-shared-from-this-without-managed-shared-pointer-in-c11 in this topic they explain why your attempt failed (Undefined Behavior if object is not already shared), and some workaround to guarantee that all the instances of your `Square` are managed by a `shared_ptr`

Comment: @the.polo *"I agree, that a non-owning pointer would make life much easier here."* -- design your code for "easier", and add adapters as needed (second part of [the Useless answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73826643/)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to use `enable_shared_from_this`, perhaps because your objects are *not* always owned by a shared pointer, you can always work around it by using a no-op deleter:

```
void nodelete(void*) {}

void Square::Computation() { DoublePerimeter({this, nodelete}); }
```

but it's a hack (and a fairly expensive one at that, since you're allocating and deallocating a control block just to con the function you're calling).

A cleaner solution, albeit one that might require more typing, is to separate your free function implementation from the ownership scheme:

```
float DoublePerimeter(Shape const& shape)
  return 2*shape.GetPerimeter();
};

float DoublePerimeter(std::shared_ptr<Shape> shape)
  return DoublePerimeter(*shape);
};

void Square::Computation() const { DoublePerimeter(*this); }
```

Answer (score 2):

I've tried it out. It seems to work for me. See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/esfWY1nvf) or below. I fixed some small issues and made Computation return a value for demonstration purpose.

```
#include <memory>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

class Shape {
    public:
    virtual float GetPerimeter(){return 0;}

};

float DoublePerimeter (std::shared_ptr<Shape> shape){
  return 2*shape->GetPerimeter();
}

class Square : public Shape, public std::enable_shared_from_this<Square> {
  float side = 1;
  public:
  Square(float aside) : side(aside) {}
  float GetPerimeter(){return 4*side;}
  float Computation() { 
      return DoublePerimeter (this->shared_from_this());
    }
};


int main(){
    auto square = std::make_shared<Square>(3.0);
    std::cout <<square->Computation() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

edit:

Example for @pptaszni's comment. Changing [the main to](https://godbolt.org/z/bE1nGbxfx):

```cpp
int main(){
    Square square{3.0};
    std::cout << (&square)->Computation() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

will result in a runtime error:

```
Program returned: 139
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_weak_ptr'
  what():  bad_weak_ptr
```

Comment: It will work only if that `Square` is already shared with `std::shared_ptr` (like in your example). However in the question it was mentioned that this approach failed, probably because instance of `Square` was not shared at the moment. OP to confirm.

Comment: When inheriting from `std::enable_shared_from_this`, I would make constructors private, and provide a factory to return a `std::shared_ptr`.